# combining php variable with shortcode in wordpress template

Tags: php, wordpress, concatenation, custom-fields, wordpress-shortcode

I have set up a content-slide.php template to replace the featured image with a smartslider 3 slider in Wordpress using the shortcode:

```
[smartslider3 slider=x]
```

where `'x'` is the id number generated by the smartslider plugin

The template allows the id number to be added via a custom field named `'Slideshow ID'` to enable the slide number to be added in edit mode.

I have tried adding the following code to the template:

```
<?php 
$slide_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Slideshow ID', true); 
echo do_shortcode('[smartslider3 slider= ' . $slide_id . ']' ); 
?>
```

The slideshow does appear, however the `']'` is being rendered on the page on one of the two slides I have added to the site. I'm very new to PHP and would really appreciate any help on where I am going wrong.

Comment: Try not echoing the `do_shortcode`.

Comment: Shouldn't the shortcode be `[smartslider3 slider="x"]` (quotes around the value of the attribute?

Comment: I have just realised that I added the shortcode in its entirety in the custom field, where I should have just included the id number. The code was being repeated!  I will leave this up in case anyone may find it useful or there are any suggestions on how to improve the code